# Angulkar2 file saver-save in ANSI format

Tags: angular, file, blob, ansi

I am using Angular4 in my app and my UI downloads a file. The file content is coming as a reponse in the format Window-1252 from Java. I am using Blob to download the text file, when I downloaded the file is saved as UTF-8 even though I specified charset-ansi, how can we resolve this? below is the code for the blob.

```
const filename = 'test.txt';
const blob = new Blob([response._body], { type: 'text/plain;charset=ansi' 
});
saveAs(blob, filename);
```

Comment: Specifying a mime-type doesn't change the actual *content* of the blob, it's just a meta-description. The actual content is likely UCS2/UTF16 since this is what JS uses for strings (i.e. the _body part if that is string type). Look at TextEncoder/TextDecoder or you could consider obtaining the original text as a binary stream (ArrayBuffer) and provide that directly to the blob instead of going via strings at all (using the same mime-type as you have already).

Comment: @K3N, Sure will try this

Comment: I noticed that as long as the output text DOESN'T contain special characters, when we do SAVEAS, it shows encoding type 'ANSI'. When output contains special characters SAVEAS shows encoding type 'UTF-8'. The response I get from backend is alwaysWindows-1252

Comment: I think there is only one way to do this, convert the data into binary using Uint8Array and then push to blob.         const uint8 = new Uint8Array(response._body.length);
    for (let i = 0; i <  uint8.length; i++) {
      uint8[i] = response._body.charCodeAt(i);
     }
    const blob = new Blob([uint8], {type: 'text/plain'});